# Delphi 5 a Simple Example for Tserversocket and Tclientsocket

Tags: delphi

provide an example in  **DELPHI 5** if is possible

lets say we have the follow code.A simple tclientsocket communicates with a tserver socket.
Everything works fine if requests from tclientsocket are coming after the process of data on event tserversocket1onReadClient.
But How i will bypass the problem when on the middle of process i am getting a new Request from socketclient1 and i havent finish yet my process?

1. do i have to Implement it in ServerType: **stThreadBlocking**
2. Do i have to Create a thread to Do the process?
3. is it a better way do this simple.

My tclientsocket string messages will not be larger than 255 chars.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, ScktComp;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ClientSocket1: TClientSocket;
    Button1: TButton;
    ServerSocket1: TServerSocket;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ClientSocket1Error(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket;ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent; var ErrorCode: Integer);
    procedure ServerSocket1ClientError(Sender: TObject;Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent;var ErrorCode: Integer);
    procedure ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
      Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
with Serversocket1 do
begin
Active:=false;
ServerType:=stNonBlocking;
port:=5052;
Active:=true;
end;

with ClientSocket1 do
begin
active:=false;
port:=5052;
Address:='127.0.0.1';
host:='127.0.0.1';
active:=true;
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ClientSocket1Error(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent;
  var ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
errorcode:=0;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientError(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent;
  var ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
errorcode:=0;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var mydata:String;
begin
mydata:=socket.ReceiveText;
///Proceccing my data now
//Line 1
//Line 2
//Line 3
//Line 4  <---- ie. when i am proccessing line 4 a new Request from clientsocket1 arrives
//Line 5
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario you describe cannot happen. When the `ServerSocket1ClientRead` event handler is executing, it will not be called in a re-entrant fashion. Well, unless you were to call `Application.ProcessMessages`. So, don't do that!

Comment: so if i have many Tclientsockets trying to send data the same time what is going to happen?

Comment: The event handler will be called many times. But not in re-entrant fashion. So the event handler is called, finishes executing, returns. Then it gets called again. And again. This is the basic model of computing. A single thread of execution does not get interrupted.

Comment: creating xxx clients and setting a sleep(10) after every sendtext  to server everything works fine.If i remove the sleep(10) i get back 40-50 responses.

Comment: Difficult to understand that. We can't see your code. It seems clear to me though that whatever your problem is, it isn't re-entrant calls of this event handler.

Comment: i create a loop for x=0 to 255 and inside loop i create 255 times a clientsocket and onconnect message i send some text.if i add inside the loop the command sleep(10) everything works fine and i receive back 256 responses from thread.

Comment: but if i remove the sleep(10) then i receive back random 40 to 50 responses.This is what i was trying to say.Everything is ok.

Comment: A single `TServerSocket` can process messages from many `TClientSocket`s. It puts the messages into a queue and process them in order of arrival.